# Undefined local variable or method - download a file - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, download, link-to

I am trying to embed a downloadable file in rails. But getting the below error:

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `home_download_pdf_url' for #<#:0x007fd9f1a2eea0>):

home_controller.rb

```
def download_pdf
  send_file(
    "#{Rails.root}/public/Brochure.pdf",
     filename: "Brochure.pdf",
     type: "application/pdf"
  )
end
```

routes.rb

```
 get 'home/download_pdf'
```

view.html

```
<%= link_to 'Download Brochure', home_download_pdf_url>
```

I am new to Ruby. Please help.

Comment: Do you have a download_pdf entry in your routes.rb file?  If so, then you need to put the action in front of the controller name in your _url method.  So, it should be download_pdf_home_url.  Give that a try and see if you get into your controller action.

Comment: `<%= link_to 'Download Brochure', home_download_pdf_url %>` Make sure you're closing the tag properly

Answer (score 0):

Your using action as

> download_pdf

so link to can be changed to

```
link_to "Download Brochure", controller: "home", action: "download_pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an older Rails, make sure you restart the server after changing the routes. You might also try alternative route syntax `get 'home/download_pdf' => 'home#download_pdf'`, run `rake routes` to make sure, you should see a line like `home_download_pdf GET  /home/download_pdf(.:format) home#download_pdf`. You can probably also link directly to the file since it's in the public dir `link_to 'Download Brochure', 'Brochure.pdf'`, and it's suspicious that your inspection of the view is `#<#:0x007fd9f1a2eea0>`, been a while since I looked at rails, but I'd expect it to have a class name there. Usually view files are `view.html.erb`, not `view.html`, and that file name name is a bit suspicious, what's the full path to the file from the rails root? I'm expecting something like `app/views/home/index.html.erb` usually the filename will be in a dir named after the controller (hence home), and the file will be named after the action (controller method that rendered it). There are deviations from these conventions, but I can't tell if yours is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The error is simple, it means you don't have a route defined with the "name" that you're referencing:

```
#config/routes.rb
get "home/download_pdf", to: "home#download_pdf", as: :home_download_pdf

#app/controllers/home_controller.rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def download_pdf
    # ...
  end
end

#app/views/home/download_pdf.html.erb
<%= 'Download Brochure', home_download_pdf_path %>
```

---

As a tip, we always put "misc" actions in our `ApplicationController`:

```
#config/routes.rb
get "download_pdf", to: "application#download_pdf", as: :home_download_pdf

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def download_pdf
    # ...
  end
end
```

--

If you *have* to use a `home` controller etc, you'll mostly want to embed any extra routes into a [`resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web) directive:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :home, only: [] do
  get :home_download_pdf, on: :collection #-> url.com/home/home_download_pdf
end
```

Comment: For the sake of posterity, you'll want to accept the answer if it worked